# Display value for element in Node.js pug template doesn't change? Also, jQuery doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, pug

Code:

```
html
    head
        title abc123
    body
        for t in things
            button(onclick="doThing('" + t + "')") #{t}
            br
        div(id='box' style='display:none;')
            input(id='boxInput' type='text')
            button
   script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript')
   script(type='text/javascript').
       var doThing = function (thing) {
           document.getElementById('box').style.display = 'block';

           var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xmlHttp.open('POST', '/doThing', false);
           xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
           xmlHttp.send('name=' + thing);
       }
```

1) So 'box' and its contents never shows after I click on one of the things. Its display value is still 'none'. Why is this?

2) I would like to use this instead of XMLHttpRequest:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/doThing',
   // etc...
});
```

but the console always comes back with 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined'. I've changed where the dots go, made a separate script for jQuery only, but I still get the same reference error. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the indenting in the code you pasted the actual indenting in you template? It looks like you `script` tags will end up outside of the `body`.